# How to include Moving Average with Pandas based on Values on other Columns

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I am trying to calculate the Moving Average on the following dataframe but i have trouble joining the result back to the dataframe
The dataframe is :  (Moving Average values are displayed in parentheses)

```
Key1 Key2 Value MovingAverage  
  1    2    1       (Nan)
  1    7    2       (Nan)
  1    8    3       (Nan)
  2    5    1       (Nan)
  2    3    2       (Nan)
  2    2    3       (Nan)
  3    7    1       (Nan)
  3    5    2       (Nan)
  3    8    3       (Nan)
  4    7    1       (1.33)
  4    2    2        (2)
  4    9    3       (Nan)
  5    8    1       (2.33)
  5    3    2       (Nan)
  5    9    3       (Nan)
  6    2    1        (2)
  6    7    2       (1.33)
  6    9    3        (3)
```

The Code is :

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Key1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6], 'Key2':[2,7,8,5,3,2,7,5,8,7,2,9,8,3,9,2,7,9],'Value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
MaDf = df.groupby(['Key2'])['Value'].rolling(window=3).mean().to_frame('mean')
print (MaDf)
```

If you run the code it will correctly calculate the Moving Average based on 'Key2' and 'Value' but i can't find the way to correctly reinsert it back to the original dataframe (df)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove first level of `MultiIndex` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for align by second level:

```
df['mean'] = (df.groupby('Key2')['Value']
                .rolling(window=3)
                .mean()
                .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)
    Key1  Key2  Value      mean
0      1     2      1       NaN
1      1     7      2       NaN
2      1     8      3       NaN
3      2     5      1       NaN
4      2     3      2       NaN
5      2     2      3       NaN
6      3     7      1       NaN
7      3     5      2       NaN
8      3     8      3       NaN
9      4     7      1  1.333333
10     4     2      2  2.000000
11     4     9      3       NaN
12     5     8      1  2.333333
13     5     3      2       NaN
14     5     9      3       NaN
15     6     2      1  2.000000
16     6     7      2  1.333333
17     6     9      3  3.000000
```

If default `RangeIndex` is possible use [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df['mean'] = (df.groupby(['Key2'])['Value']
                .rolling(window=3)
                .mean()
                .sort_index(level=1)
                .values)
print (df)
    Key1  Key2  Value      mean
0      1     2      1       NaN
1      1     7      2       NaN
2      1     8      3       NaN
3      2     5      1       NaN
4      2     3      2       NaN
5      2     2      3       NaN
6      3     7      1       NaN
7      3     5      2       NaN
8      3     8      3       NaN
9      4     7      1  1.333333
10     4     2      2  2.000000
11     4     9      3       NaN
12     5     8      1  2.333333
13     5     3      2       NaN
14     5     9      3       NaN
15     6     2      1  2.000000
16     6     7      2  1.333333
17     6     9      3  3.000000
```

Comment: I think its working as it should...checking right now

Answer (score 2):

Simply `df['mean'] = df.groupby(['Key2'])['Value'].rolling(window=3).mean().values`

Comment: This is not working ...i need to match the MA to the Key2 with Respect to Key1