# Pandas - assign groupby rolling mean results to new column respecting initial dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

My goal is to to calculate the moving average line for `avg_price` column each customer.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    customer    avg_price   avg_price2  count1  count2  rate
date_time                       
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer1   4.4656  1.25    36  11084   0.003237
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer2   7.8873  0.92    10  22150   0.000451
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer3   2.3016  1.37    1   2521    0.000397
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer4   3.2421  1.05    221 98973   0.002228
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer5   1.0050  0.94    2   410     0.004854
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer1   4.9450  1.99    340 118000  0.002873
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer2   4.0643  2.06    268 20850   0.012691
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer3   3.7034  1.00    25  5100    0.004878
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer4   5.0367  2.64    2098    118251  0.017433
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer5   2.7429  1.57    50  11900   0.004184
```

Now, I already believe I found a way to do the calculation so I'm trying to figure out a way to assign the results of this group to the dataframe as a new column.

```
df.groupby('customer')['avg_price'].rolling(50).mean()
```

The results looks like this:

```
customer  date_time          
Customer1   2022-06-11 00:00:00          NaN
            2022-06-11 06:44:00          NaN
            2022-06-11 08:07:00          NaN
            2022-06-11 08:10:00          NaN
            2022-06-11 08:20:00          NaN
                                     ...    
Customer2   2022-06-21 09:56:00    14.048820
            2022-06-21 09:57:00    14.060702
            2022-06-21 09:58:00    14.054652
            2022-06-21 09:59:00    14.024310
            2022-06-21 10:00:00    14.020486
Name: avg_price, Length: 228442, dtype: float64
```

When I tried adding this to the dataframe as a column, I got the following error:

```
df['ma_24h'] = df.groupby('customer' ['avg_price'].rolling(50).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True)

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I want to add the calculated column, the results without customer to the existing dataframe so that it respects the already existing index which the date_time column.

Comment: I think you could either group the dataframe you want to add the column to as well or you reset the index on the dataframe you want to assign so that the indices match.

Comment: I believe I found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703071/how-to-include-moving-average-with-pandas-based-on-values-on-other-columns

It involved using sort_index and getting the values.
Yea, handling the index is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a way thanks to this post: [How to include Moving Average with Pandas based on Values on other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703071/how-to-include-moving-average-with-pandas-based-on-values-on-other-columns)

```
df['ma_24h'] = (df.groupby(['customer'])['avg_price']
                .rolling('24H', min_periods=360)
                .mean()
                .sort_index(level=1)
                .values)
```

I changed the rolling to 24H. The main issue I had was with the index and getting the values and apparently I had to sort the index and just select the values.

If there are other simpler ways to accomplish this, I'm open for them.